How to convert two integers into a float?
I have a web app where I need to convert two integers into a float number. The user is requested two integer tags (WordOne and WordTwo). I have created a JavaScript function and what I have tried so far is:
function WordsToReal (WordOne, WordTwo) {
    var w1=0, w2=0, hex1, hex2, ascii1, ascii2, ascii12;
    let str;
    w1 = $getTag(WordOne); //here I get the value for tag WordOne
    w2 = $getTag(WordTwo); //here I get the value for tag WordTwo
    
    //conversion words from int to hex:
    hex1=w1.toString(16);
    hex2=w2.toString(16);
    
    //conversion from hex to ascii
    ascii1=Buffer.from('' + hex1, 'hex');
    ascii2=Buffer.from('' + hex2, 'hex');
    
    //concatenate ascii values
    str = '' + ascii1 + ascii2;
    
    //conversion from string to int and then to float
    return Number(str)/10;
    console.log("Number(str): " + Number(str)/10);
}

The integer values are read from a power meter device. Each floating value is composed of two integer value like described below. If, for example, w1=12337 (in hex:3031) and w2=14641 (in hex: 3931). 30 in ASCII is 0, 31 in ASCII is 1, 39 in ASCII is 9 and 31 in ASCII is 1. The result I get is 19.1 which is correct.
My problem is that for greater w1 and w2 values, I get other result instead of what should I get.
For example, w1=17358 (in hex: 43CE)  and w2=63971 (in hex: F9E3). 43 in ASCII is C, the other hex values (CE, F( and E3) converted in ASCII are some symbols. The float number for these two integers should be 239.4 or something very similar.
My question is if there's another method of converting two integers into float or my method could be changed to get what I want?

This seems like a random sequence of operations, which sometimes yields a float, but also sometimes doesn't. Is there any specific requirement or logic behind this, or are you merely slapping random stuff together until you get a result that looks like something you want?

very easy: (int, int) -> (byte, byte, byte, byte) -> (char, char, char, char) -> string -> float. From ur description it seems byte -> char is not working properly...that points to an encoding issue...maybe you should use utf8 instead of iso8859 or cp850 or somethin else

hex is a distraction...grab the encoding your source is using and you should get just numbers...for example 48 -> 0,...,57 -> 9

@deceze , it's not random stuff. The values are read from a power meter.  239.4 represent a voltage. This voltage is composed of two integers (17358  and 63971).

@PerdiEstaquel I didn't quite understand what do you suggest to do.

It would help if you illustrated your formula with concrete values as text, not with non-working code. It's not easy to piece together your intended calculation from non-working code.

This code works for example w1=12337 (in hex:3031) and w2=14641 (in hex: 3931). This should work also for greater w1 and w2 values. If my code can't be changed, is there any  other method to convert those integer values?

where do 17358 and 63971 come from? from the power meter? if so, the power meter manual should tell you how to make the conversion.

Yes, from power meter. But it only provides the values and not telling how to make the conversion.

so how did you get the idea to write that code?

make and model of power meter please? also a picture of the front panel would be good

It's  schneider pm5100.. I can't upload photos. Here you can find it: https://www.se.com/uk/en/download/document/EAV15105-EN/
